# How to make 1 letter fill the page dynamically

Tags: html, css

I have a single letter centred on the page. I want it to be really big (I have the font-size set at 2000%!). How do I make this responsive so that it sits centre on all screens? At the size, I have it the padding around the letter are a real problem when resizing the browser. I am trying to make flash cards for children to learn their letters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `viewport units`

**1vh = 1/100th of the height of the viewport.**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow:hidden;
}

div {
  font-size: 99vh;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>A</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/full/pEVPVY/)

Comment: I suggest `vmin` instead of `vh` since we do not know which of height/width is the shortest viewport's edge length.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `vh` (Viewport Height) to set the font size of the letter and use Flex to center it on the page :

i.e. :

```
<body>
    <div style="display: flex;justify-content: center;">
        <div style="align-self: center;">
            <span style="font-size: 95vh;line-height:1;">L</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Hope it helps.